# laravel 4.2 eloquent: get all() + related column

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-4.2

Let's say we have 2 models, with following relations:

Users:

```
public function BookCode() {
    return $this->hasOne( 'BookCode' );
}
```

BookCode:

```
public function User() {
    return $this->belongsTo( 'User' );
}
```

Now we'd like to get all records from User with book_code from BookCode (empty if none) as an array. Is something like that possible? The only thing I came up, which seems to be very slow (takes 30 secs to execute), was:

```
$users = User::all();

foreach( $users as $user ) {
    $users_array[] = array(
        $user->first_name,
        $user->last_name,

        // this is very slow
        $user->BookCode['book_code'],
        $user->created_at,
        $user->updated_at,
    );
}
```

Would it be possible to get an array of Users with related book_codes "in one go"? Couldn't find any solution to this for 5 hrs now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the relationships that should be eager loaded.

```
$users = User::with('BookCode')->get();
```